# Numerical Batch Input with Hyphen representing the sequence between two numbers

Tags: batch-file

I need to receive input in a batch file that could potentially contain a numerical hyphen, ie. 1-5 means 1, 2, 3, 4, and 5 as the input from the user.

I know how to take a single character input from the user, but to split the input into 5 (or more) separate entries kind of baffles me.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, didn't see that checkmark. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `for /f` with `delims` to split a string.  You can use `for /L` to loop over a range.  Type `help for` on the command line to read about the type of loops.

```
@echo off
set /p "input=Enter a number or range: "

REM The user must enter either a plain number or a range.  Either way, we split
REM the user input on the minus sign.  If there's no minus sign, then only
REM %upper% won't get a value.
for /f "usebackq delims=- tokens=1,2" %%a in ('%input%') do (
    set "lower=%%a"
    set "upper=%%b"
)

REM If %upper% has a value, then input was a range.  Otherwise, input contained
REM a single number.
if not "%upper%"=="" goto :handle_range

echo Single number: %lower%
goto :eof

:handle_range
echo Range %lower% to %upper%

REM We can use the numeric for loop to loop over the full range.
for /l %%i in (%lower%, 1, %upper%) do (
    echo     %%i
)

goto :eof
```

Comment: Great thanks @indiv. Now I need to use this loop (the numbers from the loop are the folder names) to recursively copy a several files with the same prefix, from a single folder, to these numbered folders. How might I go about doing that? Again thanks for your input.

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off

set /P "input=Enter a number or range: "

for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=-" %%a in ("%input%") do (
   set lower=%%a
   set upper=%%b
)
if not defined upper set upper=%lower%
for /L %%i in (%lower%,1,%upper%) do (
   echo Process number %%i
)
```